# Как сделать, чтоб кнопка реагировала на нажатия?

Tags: java, android, button, android-button

Я знаю что можно сделать `selector` и установить там разные режимы нажатия. Но ведь стандартные библиотеки сейчас очень красиво отрабатывают нажатие. Мой вопрос в том, что когда я создаю просто кнопку в пустом активити и нажимаю на нее, то она красиво делает волну от точки касания и дальше по всей кнопке, но когда я добавляю кнопке свой

```
android:background="@drawable/stylecapturebutton"
                android:src="@drawable/photocamera"
```

то она перестает так делать...

Вот код моей `ImageButton` :

```
<ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/bPicture"
                android:onClick="bPicture"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/stylecapturebutton"
                android:src="@drawable/photocamera"
                android:padding = "10dp" />
```

Можно ли как то установить в кнопку бекграунд и ресурс, чтоб при этом сохранить стандартную обработку нажатия?

Вот такая кнопка получилась

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">
        <!--<solid android:color="@color/myColor" />-->
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/color_white" />
        <size
            android:width="18dp"
            android:height="18dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/button"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="false" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/button"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button" />
</selector>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: К сожалению нельзя

Comment: @АндроидАндроид ну вот(

Comment: @АндроидАндроид так, что тогда только `selector`-ами отрабатывать? или есть еще что то?

Comment: Да, сейчас пример к ответам добавлю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я использую ripple, который и позволяет добавлять эффект волны для Видов с пользовательским цветом фона. 
1. Создаете файл разметки по адресу - ресурсы/drawable/разметка кнопки.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/color_button_светлый_цвет">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/color_button_темный_цвет" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

2. Прописываете в качестве фона ссылку на этот файл:

   android:background="@drawable/разметка кнопки"
3. Будьте внимательны, этот финт работает на версиях Андроид после 5.0. До них я использую селекторы. Для этого необходимо создать по умолчанию файлы фона в drawable через селекторы, а в папке drawable-v21 файлы фонов с ripple. Обратите внимание, папка drawable-v21 должна находится в ресурсах, т.е. на уровне папки drawable, а не внутри нее.

Comment: Отлично! То, что нужно... А скажите еще, как будет себя вести кнопка на версии ниже 5.0? Просто менять цвет без волны или совсем не будет ни какого отклика?

Comment: Ниже 5.0 будет вести себя так, как Вы пропишете в селекторах. Пока я использую 2 состояния в селекторе: по умолчанию - один цвет, и когда нажата - другой цвет. Цвет меняется резко без волны. Без селектора - так, как Вы описали в вопросе, без видимых изменений, что кнопка нажата. Вы можете попробовать как работают селекторы и на версии 6.0 и увидите сами, поподбираете цвета, а потом создадите папку drawable-v21 с ripple.

Comment: Я наверное что то упустил.  Я ж не могу использовать и ваш подход и селекторы для одного вью...  Ведь и тот и другой я устанавливаю как бекграунд,  а это означает,  что я могу установить либо селектор либо рипл...  Или не так?

Comment: Не заметил Ваш вопрос. Если еще актуально или полезно другим: и то, и другое работает одновременно. Если у пользователя андроид до 5.0, то действуют селекторы, т.е. то, что содержится в папке drawable. А если у пользователя андроид РАВНО И ВЫШЕ 5.0, то действуют ripple, т.е. то, что содержится в папке drawable-v21.

Answer (score 3):

Создайте xml-файл положите его в ресурсы `drawable`

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button"/>
```

И у вашей кнопки в атрибуте `android:background` укажите имя этой xml.

Comment: Ну это ж стандартный селектор... И под нужные положения я подставляю нужный `@drawable/button` , верно?

Comment: угу, всё верно.

Comment: А можете подсказать еще... У вас получается выбрано 4 положения на которые реагирует кнопка ... Можете обьяснить в какой момент что работает? Просто я не пойму вот допустим 1-е... чем отличается focused (set when a view has input focus.) от pressed ? И почему в пункте 2 у вас на двух этих параметрах `true`? Как это должно сработать?

Comment: Прояснить детально не могу, знаю, просто что так работает=)